# How do I connect to a wired network and a wireless network simultaneously. With wired network default

Tags: windows-7, networking

I would like to be able to connect to a wired network and a wireless network simultaneously. With wired network primary.

The idea is I want to connect to a device that is attached to a wireless access point. but have all the rest of my traffic go through to the main network.

The address for the device on the wireless network is 192.168.1.2, my primary network is a private class A (10.1.4.*)

My first problem is connecting to a wireless network with out the wireless network becoming primary.

ETA: My main wired network is my company's LAN. The wireless network I want to connect to is on a Cellular Router/modem Device. I have a BeagleBone Black connect to that router that I would like to connect to from my desktop. The Wireless BBB will have internet access though the Router, but I only need to connect to the BBB for ssh and samba. My desktop should send all it's traffic through the wired network except for the ip address to the BBB and the ip address to the router's config page.

The way I am verifying that it's not doing what I need it to do, is by trying to access web pages on my desktop when the wireless network is connected. When it's connected I can't load web pages. The cellular router has the 3G switched off right now as it is not need yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating static routes in the route table

1. Open an elevated command prompt
2. Enter 
   "route print -4" 
   This will print all the routes in the table.
3. Figure out which default route goes to your secondary network connection. There should be 2 default routes.
4. Delete that route with the command "route delete {network} mask {subnet mask} {gateway}"
5. Then add the routes that you need to access. for example I need to access 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2. They are accessed through gateway 192.168.3.1. so used the following commands
   "route add -p 192.168.1.1 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.1"
   "route add -p 192.168.1.2 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.1"

That's it. You should be able to access your network normally except for those addresses that will go to the second nic.

I found the instructions on how to do this here http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/320978-static-routes-create-remove.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the binding order of your network adapters.

Go to Network and Sharing Center and choose Change Adapter Settings. In the list of the network adapters on your system, press the ALT key to bring up the menu bar.  Click the Advanced menu -> Advanced Settings...

On the Adapters and Bindings tab, in the Connections box, it will list all the adapters in your system in the order in which they are searched.  Select the wired connection and use the up button to put it at the top of the list.  The item at the top of the list is the connection that will be tried first when you access the network (i.e. your default route).

[image]

Comment: I just tried that, no dice.

Comment: How are you verifying? Describe your scenario. What is on each network? Do both have access to the Internet? What traffic needs to be on the wireless vs. the wired?  Etc.